# Highlight grid row on edit

Tags: extjs, extjs3

I am on ExtJs3.2.
There is a gridpanel with a column having a textField as an editor.
On change of value in the textfield - i need the corresponding row to be highlighted.
How do I get the 'owning' row index of the text field?

```
 columns: [
      ...........
            {header: 'Revenues',dataIndex: 'percentage',
              editor: new Ext.form.TextField({
                     listeners: {
                        'change' : function (field, newValue, oldValue) {
                          if(oldValue!=newValue){
                         .......
                        //How do I get the row index?  
                         Ext.fly(grid.getView().getRow(row)).addClass('yellow-row');
                        }
                    }
            }
```

Is there any other way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you please try below?

```
var grid = Ext.grid.GridPanel({
    store: yourStore,
    id: 'myGrid',
    colModel: new Ext.grid.ColumnModel({
        defaults: {
            width: 120,
            sortable: true
        },
        columns: [
            {id: 'Company', header: 'Company', width: 120, sortable: true, dataIndex: 'company'},
            {header: 'Change', dataIndex: 'change'},
            {
                header: 'Revenue',
                dataIndex: 'percentage',
                editor: new Ext.form.TextField({
                    listeners: {
                        'change': function(field, newValue, oldValue) {
                            if (oldValue != newValue) {
                                var sel = Ext.getCmp('myGrid').getSelectionModel().getSelected();
                                // if you select more than one record use getSelections instead of getSelected
                                console.log(sel);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                })
            }
        ]
    }),
    sm: new Ext.grid.RowSelectionModel({singleSelect: true}),
    width: 500,
    height: 300,
    frame: true,
    title: 'My Grid'
});
```

Comment: that wouldn't work  - because in case the user selects another row after filling the field - the selected row changes.

Comment: I didn't understand. If you get selected row index, why don't you set background color?

Comment: if I fill the field Revenue on row 1;and then click on row 2 with the mouse - instead of pressing enter or tab,the getSelected() return row2 instead of row1.

Comment: Then, try to catch deselected row by `rowdeselect` event.

Comment: Is there such an event on the gridpanel?I cant seem to find an example of how to define a listener on that.I am on ExtJs3.2

Comment: Dear friend, you should look `RowSelectionModel`. When you want to get selected rows, always look selection model.